# What is the best practice for generating subordinate resources in a Rails 3 Application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

SO Community.

I am writing an app for book digitization.  A digitizer fills in a form that describes the book, e.g., title, number of pages.  I then want to generate a child resource for each page, based on the form input.

My current implementation creates the page resources in the book controller, but I'm not sure this is the "Rails" way... (code smell?)

Any recommendations on best practices?

Thank you all for your time.

Best-
Noobinator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Book model accepts the nested pages then this is fine to do it in one hit.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for